# How to return values until threshold is reached in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I'm struggling to solve a calculation problem in Excel which seems to be harder than I thought.. and I just can't find the approach I need on the internet. I will present a simplified version of what I want to get and would be eternally grateful to whoever can help me get the result.

I have the following row:

100 // 20 / 30 / 10 / 60 / 20 / 80

What I would like to see is:

100 // 20 / 30 / 10 / 40 / 0 / 0

So the first column is a total and for all the next columns, I have time-distributed values that should add up to this total and return the value that is in the cell, and at some point the amount that is needed to equal the 100 in the first cell. After that, the threshold is reached and it should return zero's.

Is there some formula for this I don't know about or an elegant way of solving this problem? Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that your original values should be overwritten with the new values? If not, can you give an example of the ranges - for example, for your first row - in which the original values lie and also in which the results should go?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to overwrite the values so that it cumulates to the '100' I have in the first column.

Comment: Then you'll certainly need VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your first row going from `A2:G2` in Sheet1 (100 / 20 / 30 / 10 / 60 / 20 / 80, respectively), you could use the following by entering the formula in cell `B2` of Sheet2 and dragging to `G2`.

```
 =IF(COLUMN(B2)=2,'Sheet1'!B2,IF('Sheet1'!B2+SUM(A2:$B2)>='Sheet1'!$A2,'Sheet1'!$A2-SUM(A2:$B2),'Sheet1'!B2))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now, I would just need to get this result in the row itself, because I have a big data sheet with hundreds of rows and I think that adding a row everytime will get quite chaotic. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to overwrite the values with a formula containing the value from the cell you are actually overwriting without using VBA. You could just create a new table and just make the cell references match up, I'll change some of the absolute references so that the formula can be copied across a whole table.

Comment: @RFM Through VBA might be the easiest way, in terms of speed. Alternative is to switch to manual calculations, enter your data (copy and paste as well), and then either switch back to automatic calculations or press F9

Comment: @RFM I've edited the answer now, so if you were to have all your data running from A2:G2 (and downwards) in 'Sheet1' and had the provided formula running from B2:G2 in 'Sheet2' it should work if copied downwards.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan, @Clauric! I think this will do the trick. I guess diving into VBA is a little too ambitious for me :)